# Use mapview in function to open viewer, but also do other things afterwards

Tags: r, sf, sp, mapview

The question may sound a little strange, but what I want to do is the following:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
data(meuse)
meuse = st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"))

plotit = function(shape){
   mapview(shape)
   print("mapview is awesome")
}

plotit(meuse)
```

It will print "mapview is awesome", but the viewer won't open. I can remove the print statement and it will open. What am I missing here?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapview` is one of those functions that only does something when its value is printed. That happens if you don't have the `print("awesome")` line because when you call `plotit` it returns the value from `mapview` and then it gets printed which triggers the web page to open. You can explicitly print the output from `mapview` and it will show:

```
 plotit =
  function(shape){
   print(mapview(shape))
   print("fixed")
  }
```

This is a similar way of operating as `ggplot` - you have to print a `ggplot` object for it to show up.

This lets you do stuff like:

```
> z = mapview(meuse) # nothing happens
> x = 1+2 # still nothing happens
> z  # shazam! here's the mapview!
> y=2+3 # it five
> z # whoosh! another mapview appears!
```

Comment: thanks a lot:) Now I got it